# Downgrade node.js - Windows

Tags: node.js

Is it even possible to manage node.js in windows? I can see examples for unix but not for Windows. I found [nodist](https://changelog.com/posts/nodist-node-version-manager-for-windows) but it looks old. Hints?

Comment: I have heard of nvm to manage node versions. Did you check it out?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Check out this project:

- https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

It's Node version manager for Windows.

Another option:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm-win

See also this tutorial:

- https://medium.com/appseed-io/how-to-run-multiple-versions-of-node-js-with-nvm-for-windows-ffbe5c7a2b47

Answer (score 17):

you can just uninstall the node from control panel and install the required node version from the node official site

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.17.0/

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

I dowloaded msi file and it works great.

Answer (score 13):

Hi you can downgrade using this command.
`npm install -g node@version`

let's assume you want to downgrade v8.11.3, the command would be
`npm install -g node@8.11.3`

Comment: I have downgraded my node version(12) but still showing my current version(16.13.0) is active.

Comment: Same here...used the command and it said that it added/modified x packages but the version wasn't changed. And yes I did open a new bash window to check what version was running. So this command didn't work for me. Is it broken????

Comment: In my case it worked, the downgraded version 16.20.0 is shown as the current version after downgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to restart your pc after using nvm for downgrade.